# how to delete mp3 file using php?

Tags: php

How to delete mp3 file using php? I tried unlink() but it didn't work. Do unlink deletes any file?

For example:

```
unlink('../../assets/users/vincent815_folder/music/eenie_meenie_-_sean_kingston.mp3');
```

I'm pretty sure it's not the path because I tried it and it played in my site.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php or permission issue.

Comment: and BTW, yes, the new POSIX standard has special rules for deleting mp3 files.. evil grin

Comment: If you _played_ it from that path (via HTTP I assume), it is entirely possible (and quite likely) that the filesystem path is different from the path relative to your site document root.

Comment: `unlink()` needs the filesystem path, not the web path relative to the doc root.

Comment: nice info. it works now, thanks.